# Can I open .aprx file from ReactJS application to launch ArcGIS Pro software?

Tags: reactjs, arcgis-js-api

Can we directly open a desktop application on a button click event from React application? I need to open a locally installed software project file to launch in desktop mode. I have an .aprx file to launch ArcGIS Pro software which I am trying to invoke from front end.

Tried to code using anchor link, but encountered error saying "Not allowed to load local resource" !

Thanks,
Paul

- Tried to invoke the .aprx file using full local path but failed.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, that isn't possible due to various security restrictions. However, if the application handles custom URL schemes (e.g. some-app://a-resource), you can redirect to those URLs which would open a browser prompting the user for confirmation if they'd like to open the application. That's the approach that web apps like Word online use to make the "open in desktop app" work.

Comment: Thanks for the response, was there any working solution implemented to achieve this in prod environment ? Like any sample scripts?!

Comment: Is the "ArcGIS Pro" software under your control? If it is, then you can [register a custom URL scheme](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app) and simply use a JavaScript `window.open('my-custom-scheme://resource')` call to ask the browser to try to open the application which handles that custom scheme (your app). If the app isn't under your control though, then you're out of luck.

Comment: My mistake, that software appears to be some map software which probably isn't under your control. A quick web search didn't turn up any URL schemes, but you might be able to find one through experimentation. In any case, I'd suggest downloading the .aprx file and asking the user to click on it instead, although that might not be the UX you're looking for

Comment: Highly appreciate the response ... as the ArcGIS Pro is a licensed software I don't have much control on the launching mechanism.  However, as experimented in web, there was a suggestion to use NodeJS to call execFile  method to invoke the software executable file.  I am trying that option and not sure whether wit will completely help in my case.  I have a constraint that I don't want to download the file to seek confirmation from user whether to allow/open the file as its not the expected UI/UX behaviour !!!

Comment: Is your app an electron app? Or is it running within a standard web browser? If its an electron app theres obviously a solution but the question should be clarified as such.